# Trigonometry Problem Solving

Tags: trigonometry

How can we estimate the height (h) of a castle surrounded by a moat, using the info below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that's supposed to be $50^\circ,$ not just $50$. Let $x$ be the distance (in meters) from the closer viewing point to the castle wall, so that the distance to the further viewing point is $x+45$ meters. Use [SOHCAHTOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohcahtoa#Mnemonics) on the two right triangles and solve the system of two equations in $x$ and $h$ for the variable $h$. (Don't estimate until the very end.)

Comment: Yes thats supposed to be 50 degrees. Could you please elaborate with solving the system of two equations? I'm having trouble with doing that.

Comment: Have you found the two equations? If so, what are they?

Comment: Yes, I have tan30=h/(x+45) and tan50=h/x

Comment: Excellent! Well, you can rewrite those as $$x+45=\frac{h}{\tan 30^\circ}$$ and $$x=\frac{h}{\tan 50^\circ}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: Do I substitute x = h/tan50 into the 1st equation? So h/tan50 + 45 = h/tan 30. Not sure how to solve that...

Comment: Good first step. Next, I'd move your $h$ terms to one side, so you've got $$45=\frac{h}{\tan30^\circ} - \frac{h}{\tan50^\circ}= h\left(\frac1{\tan30^\circ}-\frac1{\tan50^\circ}\right).$$ Rewrite that parenthetical bit as a single fraction, and then go from there.

Comment: @jaykirby: To rewrite the parenthetical part as a single fraction, we need to rewrite the fractions with a *common denominator*. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @jaykirby: Alternately, you can "clear the fractions" by multiplying both sides of the equation by $\tan 30^\circ\tan 50^\circ,$ to get $$h\tan 30^\circ+45\tan30^\circ\tan50^\circ=h\tan50^\circ,$$ then move your $h$ terms to one side, so you've got $$45\tan30^\circ\tan50^\circ=h\tan50^\circ-h\tan30^\circ= h(\tan50^\circ-\tan30^\circ).$$ Can you take the last step?

Answer (score 5):

From the diagram, $tan30^\circ$ = $\frac {h}{x+45} $ where x denotes the distance (in meters) from the closer viewing point to the wall.
also,

$tan50^\circ$ = $\frac {h}{x} $

we get,

$x+45=\frac{h}{\tan 30^\circ}$

$x=\frac{h}{\tan 50^\circ}.$

subtracting the equations, we get,

$45= h\left(\frac1{\tan30^\circ}-\frac1{\tan50^\circ}\right).$

You're done!!

Comment: so the answer is 45?

Comment: @user82306 are you familiar with algebra? If so, try to find a way to isolate $h$.

Comment: Any guidance how to do that?

Comment: $h=\frac{45}{\left(\frac1{\tan30^\circ}-\frac1{\tan50^\circ}\right)}$

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to solve this which is completely different but still gives the correct answer. Its just the first method that immediately came to my mind when I saw the question.

I look at the right triangle as two separate triangles. First I used law of sines on the triangle to the left to find the hypotenuse of the whole right triangle, the distance from the 30Deg measurement to the top of the tower. 
We have to find all the angles. Of course they all have to add up to 180 degrees:
$180-50=130$
$130+30=160$
$180-160=20$

https://pp.vk.me/c604326/v604326834/130f9/VZT0aNwcuuo.jpg
I now have all the angles for the triangle on the left to find the hypotenuse. Now we use law of sines.

hypotenuse = $45m(\sin(130\deg)/sin(30\deg))= 100.7893$

To find the proportion of the adjacent to the hypotenuse (which we already know and can just multiply the value), we use cosine.
 
$\cos(30\deg)*100.7893 = 87.286$

Then we use tangent to find that distance in proportion to the opposite (the height of the tower)

$\tan(30\deg)=0.57735026919$
$87.286*0.57735026919= 50.39$ meters

Then we can use pythagoras theorem to check that our answer is correct:
$\sqrt{87.286^2+50.39^2}=100.78$ meters

This gives me the same exact answer for the previously solved
$45/(1/\tan(30\deg)-1/\tan(50\deg)))$